# Newtonsoft.Json Deserializing Empty string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Lets say I have a object looking like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now if I try to deserialize a string using `JsonConvert` an exception is thrown when either of the properties is missing.
However, If I pass an empty string like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>("")
```

`null` is returned but no exception is thrown. How can I configure `MyObject` or the deserializer so that a `JsonException` is thrown just like when any of the required properties are missing?

Answer (score 7):

Just check for null. It's an expected behavior, as there is no object defined in an empty string :)

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>("");
if (obj == null)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate your class like this:

```
[JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)]
public class MyObject
{
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject just returns null and no exception is thrown

Comment: Strange it should work. Even in description of method Required.Always says : The Property must be defined in JSON and cannot be null.

Comment: The description I see for `JsonObjectAttribute.ItemRequired` is "A value indicating whether the object's properties are required."  So it seems to be related to an object's properties, not the object itself.  It looks like a convenience feature for targeting all the properties of a class at once instead of having to put `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` on each individual property.